# How to add alternate empty pages in ssrs report preview. i want PDF format

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

How to add alternate empty pages in SSRS report view . without header ,footer and Body. I Have 5 Pages But I want in PDF format like `One` data page next empty page so on total `Ten` pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Take Report1

1-->Insert Textbox in Header --> add below Expression

```
=iif((Globals!PageNumber)mod 2=0," ","Sequest")
```

2-->Insert Textbox in Footer --> add below Expression

```
=iif((Globals!PageNumber)mod 2=0," ",Globals!PageNumber &"of"& Globals!TotalPages)
```

3-->Click on Header & Footer open area, add below Expression to each

```
=iif((Globals!PageNumber)mod 2=0," ","Solid")
```

4-->add sub report(Report 2) with Margin Alignment

## Take Report 2

1--> Create Report without Header & Footer

2-->Create Body margin Properties with alternate Blank Pages

This is working for me you also try in this way  ----V Rajendra